# How can I hid the article container?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm relatively new to javascript and Mapbox so please bear with me. I am coding a map that is meant to show various restaurants around NYC and how they're being affected by recession. In addition to this, I am adding little columns that should hold articles I have written about said topic. However, this article container is showing up as a blank space on the right side of the screen and I can't get it to disappear. I only want it to show up when the user rolls over a specific location.

Here is the map.html for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!-- Loading ny Google Fonts link: Importing Junicode font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Junicode&display=swap">

    <!-- Setting up document metadata and viewport settings -->
    <title>New York City Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Include Mapbox JavaScript library -->
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.0.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <!-- Include Turf.js library for geospatial analysis -->
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Turf.js/5.1.5/turf.min.js'></script>

    <!-- Include Mapbox CSS styles -->
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.0.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <!-- Include jQuery library for dropdown menu -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include GeoJSON data -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="geo-data.js"></script>

    <style>
        /* Custom styling for scrollbar */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 0px;
            background: transparent;
        }

        /* Styling for the body element */
        body {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            font-family: 'Junicode', sans-serif;
        }

        /* Styling for the map container */
        #map {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
        }

        /* Styling for the article container */
        #article-container {
            display: none; /* Hide the article container initially */
            height: 100vh;
            width: 25vw;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background: transparent; /* Set the background to transparent */
        }

        /* Styling for the article place */
        #articlePlace {
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        /* Styling for the article image */
        #articleImage {
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        /* Styling for the info box */
        .info {
            padding: 6px 8px;
            font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: white;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: none; /* Hide the white text box initially */
        }

        /* Styling for the info box header */
        .info h4 {
            margin: 0 0 5px;
            color: #777;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: 'Junicode', sans-serif;
        }

        /* Styling for the popup image */
        .popup-image {
            max-width: 200px;
            height: auto;
        }

        /* Styling for the popup link */
        .popup-link {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* Styling for the red dot */
        .red-dot {
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            background-color: #FF0000;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Map container -->
    <div id='map'></div>
    <!-- Article container -->
    <div id='article-container'>
        <!-- Placeholder for article place -->
        <div id='articlePlace'></div>
        <!-- Placeholder for article image -->
        <div id='articleImage'></div>
    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript code -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            // Setting up Mapbox
            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoianRoaXJraWVsZCIsImEiOiJjbHA4ZjhvbW4yNDRvMmtvODVrdGk2b3NsIn0.qlZ1BN9uoVofxfrQhq8TwQ';

            // Creating a new Mapbox map
            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                container: 'map',
                style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
                center: [-73.9654, 40.7829],
                zoom: 12
            });

            // Adding navigation control to the map
            map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'top-left');

            // Creating a new Mapbox popup
            var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ closeButton: false, closeOnClick: false });

            // Variables for tracking hover state and map data layer
            let hoverCurrentId = null;
            var datalayer;

            // This function updates the article content
            function updateArticle(e) {
                let feature = e.features[0];
                let articleContainer = document.getElementById("articlePlace");
                let imageContainer = document.getElementById("articleImage");
                let infoBox = document.querySelector('.info'); // Select the info box

                articleContainer.innerHTML = feature.properties.article;

                // Append image HTML 
                if (feature.properties.image_path) {
                    imageContainer.innerHTML = `<img src="${feature.properties.image_path}" alt="${feature.properties.headline} Image" class="popup-image">`;
                } else {
                    imageContainer.innerHTML = ''; // This should clear the image container if no image path is provided
                }

                // Display the article container
                document.getElementById("article-container").style.display = 'flex';

                // Show the info box
                infoBox.style.display = 'block';
            }

            // Function to update the cursor style when hovering over a location
            function updateHead(e) {
                let feature = e.features[0];
                map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
            }

            // Function to remove the custom cursor style
            function removeHead(e) {
                map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
            }

            // Function to handle mouseenter event (hovering over a location)
            function startHover(e) {
                let feature = e.features[0];

                if (hoverCurrentId) {
                    map.setFeatureState({ source: 'datalayer', id: hoverCurrentId }, { hover: false });
                }

                hoverCurrentId = feature.id;
                map.setFeatureState({ source: 'datalayer', id: hoverCurrentId }, { hover: true });

                // Show the article container only for Tokyo Record Bar and International Wing Factory
                if (feature.properties.name === "Tokyo Record Bar" || feature.properties.name === "International Wing Factory") {
                    updateArticle(e);
                }
            }

            // Function to handle mouseleave event (leaving a location)
            function stopHover(e) {
                if (hoverCurrentId) {
                    map.setFeatureState({ source: 'datalayer', id: hoverCurrentId }, { hover: false });
                }
                hoverCurrentId = null;

                // Hide the article container when the mouse leaves
                document.getElementById("article-container").style.display = 'none';
            }

            // Function to draw the popup when clicking on a location
            function drawPopup(e) {
                let feature = e.features[0];
                var restaurantName = feature.properties.name;

                var coordinates = feature.geometry.coordinates.slice();
                var imagePath;

                if (popup.isOpen()) {
                    popup.remove();
                }

                // Check if the location is Tokyo Record Bar or International Wing Factory
                if (restaurantName === "Tokyo Record Bar" || restaurantName === "International Wing Factory") {
                    updateArticle(e);
                    return;
                }

                // Set image path based on the restaurant name
                if (restaurantName === "Gray's Papaya") {
                    imagePath = 'images/greyspapayagraphic.png';
                } else if (restaurantName === "Win Son's Bakery") {
                    imagePath = 'images/winson.png';
                } else if (restaurantName === "Mischa") {
                    imagePath = 'images/mischa.png';
                } else if (restaurantName === "Food Cart (Midtown)") {
                    imagePath = 'images/coffee.png';
                } else if (restaurantName === "Veniero’s Pasticceria & Caffe") {
                    imagePath = 'images/venieros.png';
                } else if (restaurantName === "Skylark") {
                    imagePath = 'images/fries.png';
                } else if (restaurantName === "2 Bros Pizza") {
                    imagePath = 'images/2bros.png';
                }

                // Display the popup with an image
                popup.setLngLat(coordinates)
                    .setHTML(`
                        <a href="/path/to/${restaurantName.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase()}.html" class="popup-link">
                            <img class="popup-image" src="${imagePath}" alt="${restaurantName} Graphic">
                        </a>
                    `)
                    .addTo(map);
            }

            // Function to remove the popup
            function removePopup(e) {
                map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
                popup.remove();
            }

            // Placeholder function for opening articles
            function openArticle() {
                // Handle opening articles if needed
            }

            // Map initialization
            map.on('load', function () {
                // Assign unique IDs to features in the GeoJSON data
                for (let i = 0; i < infoData.features.length; i++) {
                    infoData.features[i]['id'] = i + 1;
                }

                // Add the datalayer to the map
                datalayer = map.addLayer({
                    id: "datalayer",
                    type: "circle",
                    source: {
                        type: "geojson",
                        data: infoData,
                    },
                    paint: {
                        'circle-radius': ['to-number', ['get', 'radius']],
                        'circle-stroke-color': 'transparent',
                        'circle-stroke-width': 2,
                        'circle-color': '#FF0000',
                        'circle-opacity': [
                            'case',
                            ['boolean', ['feature-state', 'hover'], false],
                            1,
                            0.5
                        ]
                    }
                });

                // Event listeners for mouse interactions
                map.on('mouseenter', 'datalayer', function (e) {
                    startHover(e);
                    drawPopup(e);
                    updateHead(e);
                });

                map.on('mouseleave', 'datalayer', function (e) {
                    stopHover(e);
                    removePopup(e);
                    removeHead(e);
                });

                map.on('click', 'datalayer', function (e) {
                    openArticle();
                });

                // Fit the map to the bounds of the GeoJSON data with padding
                map.fitBounds(turf.bbox(infoData), { padding: 120, linear: true });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'd so so so appreciate anyone's help/guidance with this.

This is what I tried

```
                // Show the article container only for Tokyo Record Bar and International Wing Factory
                if (feature.properties.name === "Tokyo Record Bar" || feature.properties.name === "International Wing Factory") {
                    updateArticle(e);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: flex;` from `#article-container` and set `.mapboxgl-canvas` width to 100vw.

Comment: Thanks! So I don't think I explained my problem correctly. I do want the article container to show up, but only when I rollover certain locations. So it should pop-up when the user interacts with the specific locations if that makes sense